# How to read and analyze Elastic Search errors?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search and it's so hard to me to read and analyze it's errors. first of all I tried to format error with a JSON formatter, but it still looks like a mess. Do you use specific way to format it?  after that how can I find what is the cause of error among this huge error text? this is a sample of mine:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][0]: SearchParseException[[rep][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][4]: SearchParseException[[rep][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][3]: SearchParseException[[rep][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][2]: SearchParseException[[rep][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][1]: SearchParseException[[rep][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: did you get any insight on this ? I'd like to parse the error message, but cannot find a reference on its structure. I know it's late, but as to your problem: `Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries`